# Alternative to Java.sql.time

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime

Is java.sql.time not working properly?

This is my code

```
         Time lowertime=new Time(date.getTime());
         lowertime.setHours(lowertime.getHours()-11);
         System.out.println(lowertime);
         Time uppertime=lowertime;
         uppertime.setHours(lowertime.getHours()+1);
         System.out.println(uppertime);
         System.out.println(lowertime);
```

Result Obtained

```
02:11:13
03:11:13
03:11:13
```

The result should be:

```
 02:11:13
 03:11:13
 02:11:13
```

I searched the java docs and its deprecated.Whats the alternative to get a time range of 1 hour or (say 58 minutes).

I am using java,Hibernate Framework and MySql database.Whats the best option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Time uppertime=lowertime;
```

Due to the above line, uppertime and lowertime are two references to the same object. Each time you modify one, you also modify the other, since they are in fact a single, unique object. You need to create a copy:

```
Time uppertime = new Time(lowertime.getTime());
```

Comment: But as far as I learnt in java everything is passed(or assigned) by value.No concept of assigning it by reference.

Comment: @user2511713 references also have a value -- themselves. When you do in C, `char *p = ...; char *q = p;`, if you modify the contents via `q`, `p` "sees" the changes as well. Same in Java. It won't automagically create a copy for you.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for clearing such an important concept.I was in illusion.So suppose I have a object a and I want a copy of that object and want to store it as b.So do I have to copy all datamembers of object a to object b?Isn't there a shorter way?

Comment: @user2511713 this is entirely dependent on the object. It may have a copy constructor, or implement cloneable, or... There are infinitely many possible ways.